# How to get data after @ in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in the database that looks like this

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user@domain.com |
| 2 | user@domain2.com |
| 3 | user@domain3.com |

I have a form that looks like this

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" class="email-form" name="email-form">
  <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="email" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="submit" class="submit-email" name="submit-email" value="submit Email">
</form>
```

In the backend I'm trying to match the input email domain with the ones in the database, after "@".

What I've tried (if user enters: test@domain2.com)

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$emailDomain = explode("@",$email);
$emailDomain = $emailDomain[1];
/*I get the value domain2.com*/
```

How should I add a Query that matches `$emailDomain` with the database's email domain.

I know that if I add

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email = $emailDomain";
```

It will look for the exact email I want to look for whats after "@" in the email section

Comment: either use : `%$emailDomain%` or `%$emailDomain` or `$emailDomain%` and check which one gives you desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the part after the `@` stored in `$emailDomain`. Simply check whether the email field **contains** this value with the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email LIKE '%value%'
```

However, note that you cannot simply substitute `value` with your `$emailDomain` in the above query, as this would make it vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection). Instead, make sure to paramaterise the query, and use a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$email = $_POST["email"];
$emailDomain = explode("@", $email);
$emailDomain = $emailDomain[1];
$param = "%{$emailDomain}%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result); // Store the output in $result
```

Comment: param should have the email domain at the end and should have a `@` before: `$param = "%@{$emailDomain}";`. Otherwise if `$emailDomain == 'domain.com'` it would also find `myemail@asdf-domain.com`. Your solution would also find `domain.com@someother.com`.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach uses `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```sql
SELECT id, email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) AS domain
FROM yourTable;
```